# Floating div using css

Tags: css

i need this kind of effect in my project. there is a left corner floating red color strip. but i want to implement it for image using css. Please refer below image

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-tables.html#sec_26.6.1.

Comment: `position:fixed;left:0;top:0;`

Comment: here you go: http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `position:fixed;` for a div.

Example code

**css**

```
 #redBar {width:40px; height:200px; position:fixed; background:red;}
```

**html**

```
<div id="redBar"></div>
```

**Demo** http://jsbin.com/aqofa5

You can modify the `background` property to add your custom background image like `background:url("the-path-for-the-image").`

Answer (score 1):

It is called fixed position. Here is css that accomplishes this:

```
.element  { position:fixed; top:2%; right:2%;}
```

[More info.](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positioned div:

```
#myImgDiv
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-image: url(path/to-img.png);
}
```

If it's an image related to content, it's best to use an `<img>` tag with an alt attribute within this div.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is you DIV

```
<div id="alwaysThere"><img src="..."></div>
```

This should be CSS style:

```
#alwaysThere
{
    position: fixed; /* or absolute if you want it to be fixed page top-left */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Use **fixed** position when you want your image to stay there regardless of page scrolling and **absolute** when you want it to stay top left on your page which means it will scroll when you'll scroll the page down.

The example you provided with a link uses **fixed** hence it stays there regardless of scrolling.

Comment: If you use absolute it won't be fixed to the position of the browser window

Comment: @Antwan: I know. He only referred to link's *image* which to my understanding doesn't mean functionality as well. Hence I explained both so he can decide what he actually needs.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to be done, do the following:

```
div#divID
{ 
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   left:0px; 
}
```

This will give you the effect that this div will never leave the visible area of the browser.
Other position values are:

Static -- default

Absolute -- absolute in terms of the page, not the browser window

Relative -- relative to what it would be if the position was static

Answer (score 0):

This is already an image. It doesn't use a floating `div`.

This CSS is used for the `body`:

```
background-image: url(http://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/TR/logo-ED);
background: white;
background-position: top left;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```