# Aligning div tags side by side

Tags: css

So, this is a stupid question, but I cannot for the life of me get this to work.

I have a div tag with a div class that has a set size inside of it, and want to keep it all on one line horizontally. Right now, the first image appears above the inner div tag and the second image. I've tried adding float: left; and that seems to send the whole page haywire.

**Css**

```
#arrows {
    align: middle;
    width: auto;
    float: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.portfolio {
    align: middle;
    width: 750px;
    float: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="arrows">
    <p>
        <img src="../images/left.jpg" width="64" height="105" align="middle" />
        <div class="portfolio">
            <img src="../images/portfolio/borderpatrollogo.jpg" alt="U.S.   Border Patrol Brand Identity" width="564" height="475" align="middle" />
        </div>
        <img src="../images/right.jpg" alt="next" width="64" height="105" align="middle" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Look up floating rules in CSS, inherit won't work here.

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862583/floating-div-using-css

Comment: align:middle  **is not valid**